# Using xib file in three20 project

Tags: iphone, three20

Sorry if this question has already been answered but I can't find an answer.
Here are some steps I did in three20 project and the problem:

1. I created a three20 class file inherited from `TTViewController: TestTTViewController`
2. Next, I created a xib file (New File -> User Interface -> View XIB..): TestTTView.xib

And the problem is that I can't map TestTTView.xib file with class `TestTTViewController` in Interface Buider (In inspector -> Class Identity, TestTTView.xib don't detected class TestTTViewController).

In the three20 sample's TTNibDemo, I can see that the xib files can recognize their TTViewController class. What's wrong in my steps?
 
I'm sorry if my description is not enough to understand. Please let me know if you need more.

Thanks for your attention.
Tien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have exactly same issue.
I actually opened the UI sample in Xcode, then added MyViewController : TTViewController,
I added a new Nib file to the project, but could not set the nib's class ID to MyViewController in InterfaceBuilder.
Already tried reloading all class file in IB, didn't work.

I guess IB could not recognize TTViewController, so MyViewController is not recognized as a class.
Is there anyone experienced this issue before?

**UPDATE: Here's the solution: Just drag n drop all relevant Three20's header files to IB's xib window. IB will now recognize Three20's classes**

Answer (score 0):

See the UI sample in three20, it should be a good startingnpoint for you